# not able to set plotly plot yaxis range properly

Tags: python, plotly, line-plot

Hi I am having trouble getting a lineplot to display properly. I have two axes and 5 line plots on one figure. The first y-axis limit cannot be set. I tried setting the `range` property to `[0,2]`, however it doesn't do anything and continues to show from -2 to 4. I want the straight linear plot to overlay directly on top of the other 4 line plots and I don't know why the x-axis starts from -5. Can someone help fix the issue?

```
fig = go.Figure()

xs = np.linspace(0,12.5,plot_df.shape[0])

for cn in plot_df.columns:
    ys = plot_df[cn].to_numpy()
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=xs, y=ys,
                        mode='lines',
                        name=cn)
                        )
    
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=xs, y=xs,
                    mode='lines',
                    name='mob. grad', yaxis="y2")
                    )

fig.update_layout(
        title = "UV and Mobile phase trace of {}".format(field_dict['sample_name']),
        xaxis = dict(
            title = "Minutes",
            domain=[0.2, 1]
        ),
        yaxis = dict(
        scaleanchor = "x",
        title = "UV Abs",
        range = [0,2],
        position = 0.19
        ),
        yaxis2 = dict(
        title = "Mobile Phase (%)",
        anchor="free",
        domain=[0.1,1],
        overlaying="y",
        side="left",
        position=0.08,
        range=[0,100])

    )
fig.show()
```

[image: plotly plot in python]

Comment: Please provide full code with a data sample.

Answer (score 0):

I just removed `scaleanchor = "x"` and it showed up properly.